# Is it possible to create App Clip without a web server

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-appclips

I have an app that works offline only and doesn't need a web server. I want to create an app clip for this app but most tutorials out there say I need to add a domain to my web server.

I want to share this app clip URL to my users using Messages.app. Can someone guide me to a working solution?

Comment: I think you might be able to use GitHub pages for this. I'm not completely sure, though.

Comment: You would still need your own domain.  I also don't know if you can publish a site association file, but you could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a web site so that you can create an association between your domain and the App Clip/App. See [Associating your App Clip with your website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website).

The URL you use to invoke an App Clip is a URL from your web site (say `https://my.domain.com/MyGreatApp` - iOS uses the domain association to link this URL to your App Clip and App.  When the user accesses this URL from their device it knows to either offer the App Clip, launch the App Clip (if the user already has it) or launch the full app (If the user has installed it).

Without a domain and a website there is no way you can provide a URL to launch your App Clip.

If you [add a smart banner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/supporting_invocations_from_your_website_and_the_messages_app) to your web site then the user also gets an improved experience in the Messages app; They see an App Clip card that shows information about your app rather than a simple text link.